# Migration from Pentaho Data Integration to Talend Data integration / Big Data

Tags: postgresql, migration, talend, pentaho-data-integration

I wanted to know the feasibility of migration of group of data processes on Pentaho Data Integration to Talend. By knowing databases are in POSTGRESQL.

It is possible ? Complicated ? Impossible ?

If it is possible, what are the requirements ?

My question is simple, can you help me ? :)

*Juju*

Comment: Could you please give an example of a data integration process that you would like to migrate ?

Comment: For example, one job configured on Pentaho. One job which is composed of many transformations. I would like to recover the same job with the same transformations on Talend. Do you know if it is possible ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tool that can migrate a Pentaho job to Talend. If you have the job specs, you can develop your Talend job based on those; otherwiser, you'll have to reverse-enginner your Pentaho process: by looking at your Pentaho job, and creating an equivalent job in Talend.

Comment: Ok, i understand! But by searching on internet, i found software of conversion ETL to other ETL --> Bitwise conversion ETL (https://cdn.bitwiseglobal.com/media/2017/12/Bitwise_Talend-Services.pdf) even with this kind of software, we can't convert Pentaho to Talend ? Do you know this tool ?

Comment: I was not aware of it. But it doesn't seem to handle Pentaho.. Reading the document, it seems to suggest that it's a consultancy firm that you need to hire to handle the migration process..